# How to change time format in Playhead Position on Premiere Pro CC 2015

Tags: video, configuration, adobe-premiere

This is how it is (there is only numbers):
[image]

That is what a want (time is separated in hours, minutes and seconds):
[image]

Comment: this is a type of "RTFM" question, you can find the answer by checking the Premiere help section or maybe the Adobe website. Or google.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

maybe is this? not sure, but I just tried it to fix mine =^=

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. What are we looking at here? can you explain how this image answers the question? We are looking for answers that are a bit longer, with some explanation. Take some time to write a proper answer!

Comment: right click on the sequence bar should display these settings to you.